# How to optimize this OpenCL kernel?

Tags: c, optimization, opencl

I'm working on a project and I've got some problems with this OpenCL kernel :-(

```
__kernel void gemm_fast_5(
    __global double *ar, __global double *br, __global double *cr,
    __global double *pr, __global double *ur,

    unsigned long c, unsigned long c2,
    unsigned long c3, unsigned long c4,
    unsigned long c5, unsigned long m,
    unsigned char com
){
    unsigned long i = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned long j = get_global_id(1);

    unsigned long x = get_local_id(0);
    unsigned long y = get_local_id(1);

    unsigned long cur = i*c3 + j, rl, rl2, rl3;

    #if ks == 1 || ks == 2 || ks == 3 || ks == 4
    unsigned long rl4;
    #endif


    #if ks == 2
    rl = (i << 1)*c;
    #elif ks == 3
    rl = ((i << 1) + 1)*c;
    #else
    rl = i*c;
    #endif

    __local double ut, pt;

    if (x == 0) pt = pr[i*c4 + ks];
    if (y == 0) ut = ur[j*c5 + ks];

    double aa = 0.0;

    double bb, cc;
    double dd, ee;

    for (unsigned long k=0; k<m; k++){
        #if ks == 1 || ks == 4
        rl3 = (k << 1) + 1; rl4 = (k << 2) + 3;

        bb = ar[rl + rl3 - 1]; cc = ar[rl + rl3];
        dd = br[rl2 + rl4 - 1]; ee = br[rl2 + rl4 - 3];
        #elif ks == 2 || ks == 3
        rl3 = (k << 2) + 3; rl4 = (k << 1) + 1;

        bb = ar[rl + rl3 - 3]; cc = ar[rl + rl3 - 2];
        dd = br[rl2 + rl4]; ee = br[rl2 + rl4 - 1];
        #else
        rl3 = (k << 1) + 1;

        bb = ar[rl + rl3 - 1]; cc = ar[rl + rl3];
        dd = br[rl2 + rl3]; ee = br[rl2 + rl3 - 1];
        #endif

        aa += (bb + dd)*(cc + ee);
    }
    cr[cur] = aa - pt - ut;
}
```

While working, I noticed that if I delete the last line, the kernel takes 6 times less to run even changing the last line with `cr[cur] = 5.0 - pt - ut;` for example.

Shouldn't it take the same, or something similar at least?
Even looking for an answer, taking advantage of the fact that I have CPU and GPU, I have tried in several runtime (PoCL and opencl-amd) and the same thing happens :-/

I would be very grateful if someone would give me a hand in making me understand why this happens. I don't understand :"v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the operations inside the loop do not have side effects, you only read from those `__global` pointers, and you calculate some temporary values that in the end get accumulated into `aa` through that final `aa += ...`. In other words, the sole purpose of that loop is to calculate the value of `aa`.

Therefore, if you remove `aa` from the last line (outside the loop), all the operations inside the loop are completely useless, and you end up with a loop that does nothing except reading some values and updating local variables that will get discarded at function return. Compiling the above code with optimizations enabled (which I assume you are doing, otherwise your question wouldn't make much sense), the compiler is very likely to just get rid of the entire loop. Hence, the code without that final `aa` runs a lot faster.

Here's [a GCC example](https://godbolt.org/z/4458rs) (adapted removing CUDA annotations), where you can see that even the lowest level of optimization (`-O1`) removes the entire body of the loop, leaving only comparisons and the incrementing of `i`. With `-O2`, [the whole loop is removed](https://godbolt.org/z/EbqfvP).

Comment: I never thought that compilers would do that, I thought they didn't care: v

Comment: @EnriqueMiguelMoraMeza welcome to the magical world of compile-time optimization!

Comment: Yes, i use it a lot, but honestly I never thought that they would get to delete an entire loop :v ¡Wow!